Migrate from deprecated XYZ with tileUrlFunction to TileImage with tileLoadFunction
The latest Openlayers documentation states that tileUrlFunction is deprecated in XYZ source. I am trying to migrate to TileImage with tileLoadFunction, but nothing is showing.
The old version is working:
Number.prototype.mod = function (n) {
    return ((this%n)+n)%n;
};

var mylayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZ({
        tileUrlFunction: function (tileCoord, pixelRatio, projection) {
            console.log("tileUrlFunction invoked");
            if (tileCoord === null) {
                return undefined;
            }

            var z = tileCoord[0];
            var x = tileCoord[1];
            var y = tileCoord[2];
            var zfactor = Math.pow(2, z);
            const url = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + z + "/" + x.mod(zfactor) + "/" + y.mod(zfactor) + ".png";
            return url;
        },
        tileSize: 256,
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 19,
        attributions: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    })
});

This is not working (tileLoadFunction is never invoked):
Number.prototype.mod = function (n) {
    return ((this%n)+n)%n;
};

var mylayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new TileImage({
        tileGrid: createXYZ({
            tileSize: 256, // Standard tile size for OpenStreetMap
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 19, // OpenStreetMap supports zoom levels 0-19
        }),
        tileLoadFunction: function (imageTile, src) {
            console.log("tileLoadFunction invoked");
            const tileCoord = imageTile.getTileCoord();
            if (!tileCoord) {
                console.log("Tile coordinate is null");
                imageTile.getImage().src = ''; // Handle undefined tile coordinate
                return;
            }

            const z = tileCoord[0];
            const x = tileCoord[1];
            const y = tileCoord[2];
            const zfactor = Math.pow(2, z);
            const url = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + z + "/" + x.mod(zfactor) + "/" + y.mod(zfactor) + ".png";

            console.log("Loading URL for coordinates - " + z + "," + x + "," + y + " --> " + url);
            imageTile.getImage().src = url;
        },
        attributions: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    }),
});

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yertp50n/

I noticed you added tileGrid, are you sure the correct tiles are requested. So the view actually contains your data?, And do you see anything in network/console?

In this case the tileGrid contains default values as per the OpenStreetMaps source (they are different in my own tiles). Removing it does not lead a different result. There are no errors in console and no tiles are requested in the network tab.

The docs suggest using an ImageTile, not TileImage source.
An ImageTile source uses a loader similar to a DataTile source (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/pmtiles-elevation.html) not a tileLoadFunction:
function loadImage(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.addEventListener('load', () => resolve(img));
    img.addEventListener('error', () => reject(new Error('load failed')));
    img.src = src;
  });
}

var mylayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new ImageTile({
        tileGrid: createXYZ({
            tileSize: 256, // Standard tile size for OpenStreetMap
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 19, // OpenStreetMap supports zoom levels 0-19
        }),
        loader: async function (z, x, y) {
            console.log("loader invoked");
            const zfactor = Math.pow(2, z);
            const url = "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/" + z + "/" + x % zfactor + "/" + y + ".png";
            const image = await loadImage(url);
            return image;
        },
        attributions: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    }),
});

https://jsfiddle.net/yt93g5za/1/

This works perfectly, thanks for clarifying. That said, it seems more elaborate and counter-intuitive than the old version. Do you know if there is any reason behind? Better performance? Or just a design change?

About the comment on mod, note that I use a prototype that gives me a positive mod (edited the question to add the prototype).

This new approach works fine in normal Openlayers/2D mode. But when using ol-cesium/3D, the loader is not invoked.

ImageTile seems like an attempt to make things more like a DataTile source.  The current version 2.20.0 of ol-cesium https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/blob/master/CHANGES.md predates version 10 of OpenLayers, so it is probably unaware of ImageTile sources or how to handle them.  Note that deprecated means a feature will be removed in a later version, so avoid using it, but 'tileUrlFunction' and tileLoadFunction do still work in version 10.
